# Dans/à/sur la côte Est

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, géographie

> Il habite dans la côte Est des États-Unis.

ou

> Il habite à la côte Est des États-Unis.

ou

> Il habite sur la côte Est des États-Unis.

Lequel est correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En général, on habite *sur* une côte, donc :

> Il habite **sur** la côte **e**st des États-Unis.

Le mot *est* est en minuscules puisque ce n'est pas un nom propre.

Mais quand « côte de … » est considérée comme le nom d'une région, et pas seulement comme une description, on utilise *dans*. Dans ce cas, l'expression est un nom propre, donc il faut une majuscule à *côte*.

> Il habite **dans** la **C**ôte est des États-Unis.
>   Il habite **dans** la **C**ôte est.

La capitalisation est un peu floue dans ce cas : on trouve aussi « Côte Est » et même « côte Est ». Je trouve « côte Est » un peu bizarre, mais c'est grammaticalement correct (*Est* est un nom propre en apposition au nom commun *côte*), et c'est l'orthographe choisie par l'auteur de l'[article de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B4te_est_des_%C3%89tats-Unis).

Il y a quelques régions françaises dont le nom est formé sur ce modèle, par exemple la [Côte d'Azur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B4te_d%27Azur) (pas une entité administrative) et la [Côte-d'Or](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B4te-d%27Or) (un département). Du coup la juxtaposition de *dans* et *côte* ne choque pas.

Il y a une différence de sens entre « sur la côte est » et « dans la Côte est ». Quelqu'un qui habite *sur* la côte doit être près de la mer, alors que la région « Côte est » est beaucoup plus grande.

Tout ceci explique le principe. En pratique, les gens ne font pas toujours attention, et le concept de région « East Coast » n'est pas tellement connu en France. Donc « côte est des États-Unis » et « Côte est [des États-Unis] » sont souvent interchangeables et l'utilisation de *dans* ou *sur* est un peu floue. S'il est vraiment important de les distinguer, il faut préciser, par exemple : « près de la côte Atlantique », « dans la région Côte est ».

On ne dit pas « à la côte » en France, sauf quand il s'agit d'une destination (aller à la côte) (ou [dans une expression figurée](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-a-la-cote.php)). En France, on ne peut pas « *<s>habiter à la côte</s> ». Ça se dit par contre en Belgique : on dit « à la côte » (sous-entendu la côte Belge) là où en France on dirait « au bord de la mer ».

Comment: J'entends, lis et utilise souvent "à la côte" pour désigner la côte comme une position et non une destination (ex: *il possède une maison à la côte, je suis actuellement à la côte, le vent souffle fort à la côte*). Mais habitant en Belgique, *la côte* désigne couramment la côte belge. Peut-être est-ce un belgicisme ?

Comment: @Greg J'ai effectivement vu ça sur le web pour la côte Belge, mais pas pour d'autres côtes (par exemple, [à la côte normande](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22%C3%A0+la+c%C3%B4te+normande%22), c'est toujours une destination, ou une expression comme « fidèle à » ou « attachement à »). Ça ne se dit pas de par chez moi (Normandie, Île-de-France). Merci de la confirmation, j'ajoute une mention à ma réponse.

Comment: Reste à savoir comment les Suisses désignent leur bord de mer  : )

Comment: J'ai toujours entendu ***sur** la côte d'Azur* et jamais ***dans** la Côte d'Azur* qui semble tellement rare que j'aurais plutôt tendance à le considérer comme erroné. C'est peut-être parce que la Côte d'Azur désigne uniquement le littoral et pas l'arrière pays qui fait partie de la Provence, mais à part *dans la Côte-d'Or*, je n'ai pas l'habitude d'entendre *dans la côte*.

Comment: @jlliagre La Côte d'Azur n'a pas de définition précise (ce qui limite l'utilisation de *dans*), mais dans certaines acceptions c'est quand même nettement plus que le littoral. Vu du nord de la France, « dans la Côte d'Azur » peut vouloir dire « dans la région Provence-Alpes-Côte-d'Azur ». Et l'expression est aussi employéee localement, [exemple](http://www.agenceducapdantibes.com/cote-azur/).

Comment: L'imprécision de la définition tient essentiellement à sa limite occidentale (Cassis, Bandol ou Hyères). Oui, il existe quelques rares occurrences de ***dans** la Côte d'Azur*, mais trop rares pour être grammaticales. L'exemple cité n'est pas exempt de fautes de grammaire, de coquilles ou de français approximatif: La région comprend **les** villes mondialement connues comme Saint-Tropez, avec comme toile **d** fond, **promener** le long du front de mer, pour se rendre dans les endroits, si l’on se rend au même café **ou la** même plage, etc.

Comment: Si je vivais à Dijon, je n'habiterais pas _dans la_ Côte-d'Or mais _en_ Côte-d'Or.

Comment: Personnellement je dirais "il habite en côte d'Azur"

Answer (score 2):

Québécois ici. On peut également dire *habiter la côte est* sans préposition (comme on dit parfois, du moins au Québec, *habiter la rive nord*). Je ne sais si cet usage (une extension des formules avec des adverbes plus généraux comme *ici, là là-bas* etc.) est aussi d'un usage plus général.

Quand il y a préposition, ici, on emploie unique *sur*. À mon avis, cela découle directement de ce que c'est (à ma connaissance) la préposition correcte en l'absence du spécifique *Est*:

> Il habite sur la côte. (correct)
>
> * Il habite dans la côte. (nongrammatical)

Comment: Oui, c'est la bonne réponse. **Dans la côte** est une hérésie linguistique et géométrique des deux côtés de l'Atlantique. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi la réponse de Gilles qui est d'habitude mieux inspiré a reçu tant de votes positifs...

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne suis pas familier avec _dans la Côte est_. Je dis _sur la côte est_ ou _dans l'est des É.-U._, mais je l'entends mieux pour des régions plus traditionnelles comme en France on dirait. Je ne sais pas. Mais je sais qu'on dit ici _dans le bas du Fleuve_, c'est une région et une description à la fois. Je suis essentiellement d'accord que sans le complément _est_, je trouve _dans_ inusité. Mais je pense que c'est possible mais très rare, avec un sens de [_côte_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542330) en aménagement du territoire... Intriguant. Merci !